# typo3 resize in plugin quality of jpg

Tags: image-processing, typo3

im sucessfully resizing miages in my typo3 plugin, but i have a problem with quality of resized images. I tried manye differend thing but the image quality stays the same.

MY CODE:

```
$imgConfig['file'] = 'GIFBUILDER';
$imgConfig['file.']['quality']  = 99;
$imgConfig['file.']['jpg_quality']  = 99;
$imgConfig['file.']['backColor'] = '#ffffff'; 
$imgConfig['file.']['transparentColor'] = '#ffffff';
$imgConfig['file.']['10'] = 'IMAGE';
$imgConfig['file.']['XY'] = '[100.w],[100.h]';
$imgConfig['file'] = $entry['image_small'];
$origImg = $this->cObj->IMAGE($imgConfig);
$resizedImageInfo = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->lastImageInfo;
```

I also set values in install tool:
[GFX][jpg_quality] = 99
[GFX][png_truecolor] = 1

I use the extension JB GD Resize (jb_gd_resize), but i dont think this is the problem. What more could i try?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the install tool http://yoursite.com/typo3/install in the "Image Processing" section  if everythings running fine there.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I use the extension JB GD Resize (jb_gd_resize), but i dont think this
>   is the problem.

You are wrong. This **IS** the problem. Have a look at the source of jb_gd_resize (1.1.5) it just uses

```
imagejpeg($newIm,$output);
```

The third parameter of [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) which is "quality" is not used at all. So default is used and you get quality around 75 independent of any other setting.